# CheckboxListTile - too many positional arguments

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to add a `CheckboxListTile` and found the checkbox code from `flutter dev` and tried to implement it in my widget shown below. But I get errors

**Error:** `too many positional arguments`, `positional arguments must occur before named arguments`

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

     @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     bool _checked = true;
    return Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
                    
                  Container(
                    
                    width: widget.sentenceWidth,
                    child: CheckboxListTile(
                      title: Text('me, the label'),
                      controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
                     value: _checked ,
                      onChanged: (bool value) setState(() {
                      _checked =  value;
                      }
                  ),),),
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code:

You have passed **bool** as type of variable in **onChange**. I have also changed width param so also check for that param might be passed wrongly.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool _checked = true;
    return Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(
              width: 500,
              child: CheckboxListTile(
                title: const Text('me, the label'),
                controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
                value: _checked,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  print(value);
                },
              ))
        ]);
  }
```

Try this and do let me know if you get any problem.

Comment: bool _checked = true; under build context, it would not be updateable because it was used in buildContext,  need to declare over buildContext